# Ubuntu 15.04 PlayOnLinux Evernote can't edit notes

Tags: 15.04, wine, playonlinux, evernote

Just installed Ubuntu 15.04 (yes, I know that I'm a slowpoke). On Ubuntu 14.10 I was using Evernote via POL and everything was OK.

Now I have a weird problem. Everything is synced. I can see a list of my notes but...

I can't edit any. I only see the title, text but I can't change it. In main list I only see content of the first note. When I select another note - nothing changes, I only see the first note.

I can Open note in new window - I see it correctly but I can't edit it.

What's it and how to fix it?

POL 4.2.5 wine 1.7.52
Evernote 5.9.1

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem under Ubuntu 14.04, using POL 4.2.9, wine 1.7.52, Evernote 5.9.1.8742. Help appreciated.

Comment: According to [WineHQ Bugzilla – Bug 39335 – Evernote 5.9.x - cannot browse or edit notes](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39335), this is an issue with Evernote 5.9.* and the only workaround suggested is to use version 5.8.

Comment: I'm now running version 5.8.3.6507 and it works fine. Notes can be edited. This version can be downloaded from here http://www.oldapps.com/evernote.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing internet explorer 8 ?

It seems to fix the editing issue

[from WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33338)